# how can I repeat a process in intent service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have my intent service which does this work:

```
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    String add = intent.getStringExtra("address");
    int porta = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("port"));
    InetAddress serverAddr = null;
    try
    {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(add);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, porta);
        socketHandler.setSocket(socket);
        sendMessagetoUI("CONNECT");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
        out.print("INIT");
        out.flush();
        char [] buffer = new char[1024];

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(readeIn));

        while((counter = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
          String s = new String(buffer,0,counter);
            Log.d("Received:",s);

        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){}
    catch(UnknownHostException e) {}
}
```

and it works well...but now I need to do this: every five minutes I need to have a task which sends a request to the server (a keep alive message created from my server)...how can I do this? I have to implement it in the while loop?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Make use of AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: You can send the request to intent service every five minute , it takes the task in its queue, it will executes it one after other

Comment: Could I use AlarmManager in onHandleIntent function?

Comment: @PreethiRao I don't understand how you want to say..I call some time onHandleIntent?

Comment: Intent yourIntent= new Intent(this, YourIntentService.class);
yourIntent.putExtra(YourIntentService.PARAM_IN_MSG, strInputMsg);
startService(yourIntent);

Comment: @PreethiRao thanks, but if I want only to send a string to server? I need to create a new IntentService, sure?

Comment: if u want repeat same onHandleIntent(Intent intent) procedure then this is what you have to follow.. it will not create new instance of intentservice, the request is submitted to the same intentserivce

Comment: @PreethiRao ok but if I call the same intent service, tcp connection breaks down but I need to send a request to server for know if it's discoverable...

Comment: you want to establish connection and keep pinging it ?

Comment: @PreethiRao  Yes, in onHandleIntent I've created the TCP connection and I want to ping the connection: if I send keep_alive, server answers me keep_yes and so I know the connection is up...

Comment: In that way you can use alram manager or timer , but one problem you will face it stopping intentservice , that you have to manage somehow , other wise it will be keep running

Comment: @PreethiRao so in this case connection breaks down?

Answer (score 0):

You can add timer..

```
Timer pingTimer = new Timer(); 
    pingTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //ping server

            }
        }, 0, mTimeRate);
```

mTimeRate will be in milliseconds,
Above case connection will not break down ,

**Things you have to consider**

When you want to stop pinging , and how will you send request to intentservice, (by binding to activity or some other way)

Comment: yeah, i think it will run in separate thread, u can check about using alram manager as well

Comment: thats what intentservice doesn't have a method to stop it.. it will be stopped only when its task is complete.. if u put a infinite loop it will be running continuously... so try using the service instead of intent service .. and onDestroy call back of your service cancel your timer

Comment: ok I've solved it, but I can't use inputStream inside the runnable, why?

Comment: you can use.. no problem... btw what did you do ?

Comment: make sure the things you r using inside runnable are final objects or member variables ..

Comment: I want to solve this problem: I send a "ping" message, but if I remove ethernet cable from the server, my app doesn't listen it and if in the timer task I send message, connection doesn't break down (it send a message, but where? Tcp connection is down)

Comment: When you send a message .. it will try sending no matter whether your server is up or down.. try checking once you send message you will get a response.. depending on response you can decide whether the server is up or down